# Help hunting down a program that is auto starting

Tags: 16.04, reboot

I need help locating where a program is starting at boot. I have remove it from crontab, cron.d .... init.d. But it is still there after reboot. Any suggestions?? or maybe a list of all the possible (reasonable) ways it could be starting after boot.

THanks

Comment: Why not mention the program?

Comment: @DK I could tell you, but then I would have to shoot you :). Joking aside, the program is part of sphinxsearch, it is called searchd.

Comment: @NealM We don't do that here. We send people to the Harmony Hut instead.

Comment: @K7AAY - I'm more humane than that.

Comment: @K7AAY - snap, snap.:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Startup Applications in **Tweaks** or **Startup Applications Preferences**?

Screenshot below for reference:
[image: Screenshot for reference]

Comment: Thanks for effort in getting the screen shoot. But I am using a console.

Comment: @NealM and that's something else you could have mentioned in the question itself :D

Comment: Hi @NealM, did you try service --status-all?

Comment: Just tried that. It appears that it is not running as a service. Yet, I am getting other indications that it is running. Something is monitoring the port assigned to it.

Comment: Maybe it is triggered upon login in the .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile?

Comment: It appears that I missed looking in the rc.local script. It was there. I commented it out, and it stopped running at boot.

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

It was hiding in `rc.local`. It appears that I just missed looking there.